# Popover issue on iPad hybrid (cordova) application

Tags: javascript, cordova, ipad, ios11, ipad-2

I am working on adding iOS 11 support for an hybrid app build on older version. Everything works fine but I am facing issue on iPad. Unable to dismiss the pop over because it keeps on reappearing after making a selection. This also happens when the orientation changes. Has anyone faced similar issue or any pointers on why this might be happening. [image]

Comment: what kind of popover?

Comment: @jcesarmobile uploaded image in the description

Comment: well, that image is from Android. Is the popover that appears when you have a html select element?

Comment: Just for your reference I have uploaded the image from the Google and yes the selection happens when we tap on an text field (html element).

Comment: when you tap on a regular text field a popover won't appear, so, are you using a plugin to show a popover? or are you using a select tag like this? ```<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>```